# using this on an objects method is returning an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I feel my whole understanding of `this` has been thrown up in the air.

I have a `Quiz` object which holds the necessary variables and methods required to play the quiz.

I am trying to reference a method of Quiz from another method in Quiz (`getQuestion` in `skipQuestion()`) however, I am seeing a message in the console saying that `this.getQuestion` is not defined. I was under the impression that `this` in this case refers to the object it is in, hence the function in question should be referred to as `this.getQuestion()`.

The error message I am getting is `script.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: this.getQuestion is not a function`

Can anyone explain what is going wrong here?

In my `init` function it seems that `this` refers to the `Quiz` object, but in `skip question` it seems to change. Is this down to query having a different definition of `this`? where do you draw the line, and when is the context of `this` changed?

```
(function(window){

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var Quiz = {

            score : 0,
            question: '',
            answer: '',

            init: function() {
                this.getQuestion();
                this.checkAnswer();
                this.skipQuestion();
            },

            skipQuestion: function() {
                $('#skip').click(function(){
                    this.getQuestion();

                })
            },

            getQuestion: function() {
                $.get('http://jservice.io/api/random', function(data){
                    $('#question').html(data[0].question);
                    this.answer = data[0].answer.toLowerCase();
                });
            },

            checkAnswer: function() {
                if($('#answer').val() === this.answer) {
                    this.score += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        Quiz.init();
    });

})(window);
```

Comment: Once you go inside another function, your `this` context changes. You either need to store the `this` you want to use as another variable before opening another function block, or you can use double arrow functions to not use a context like that altogether. The issues is: `function(){  this.getQuestion(); })`, which you can solve by doing this: `var that = this; function(){  this.getQuestion(); })` or by using an arrow function: `() => { this.getQuestion() }` (which has no `this` object associated with it).

Comment: just note that you need to run on an ES6 env to use the arrow function

Comment: @somethinghere but how come in my `init()` function it knows what the other functions are by using `this` but not in the `skipQuestion` method? Is it because of query having  different meaning of `this`?

Comment: Arrow functions do have a this associated with them, but it is auto bound to the caling context so you don't have to do 'var self = this'

Comment: Because you have wrapped the call to this.getQuestion inside _another_ function, which does _not_ have the same context as the parent function, and therefor no direct access to that `this`. @ste2425 For simplicity you can say that they don't really have an associated context. Also, they don't allow calling or applyging with another context, so it doesn't _really_ matter when writing code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are nesting inside another function, the `this` context changes to *that function*, so the methods you look for are no longer available. You can try to solve it by either storing the `this` inside a variable that will be within the scope of the function you are defining, or by using Double Arrow Functions, which have no associated `this` context themselves (and therefor also don't support `bind` or `call`). Here are your options:

Declare a variable:

```
skipQuestion: function() {
    var that = this;
    $('#skip').click(function(){
        that.getQuestion();
    })
}
```

or a **Double Arrow Function**:

```
skipQuestion: function() {
    var that = this;
    $('#skip').click(() =>  that.getQuestion())
}
```

Your init function is considered a **method** of your Quiz object, while the *anonymous* function passed to the click event is **not** a method of your Quiz, it is a method of an *anonymous object* created in the background, and shares no methods or variables with your Quiz. This is important to consider!

Comment: but it isn't as simple as being inside another function is it? as `this` in the `init` function refers to the Quiz object?

Comment: It is actually as simply as that. As soon as you nest it inside another function, `this` refers to _that_ function, not the function a level higher. Every `function` gets a new `this` context, which will be empty. But functions directly attached to an object get `this` set to the object - which an anonymous function obviously is not.

Comment: ok! but in this case in my `init` function the `this` refers to `Quiz`? if so can you explain why?

Comment: Your `init` function is considered a **method** _of_ your `Quiz` object, while the _anonymous_ function passed to the click event is _not_ a method of your `Quiz`, it is a method of an anonymous object created in the background, and shares no methods or variables with your `Quiz`. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, it does help thanks! would you mind adding that to your answer?

Comment: What would be the difference of `this` inside the `skipQuestion` function versus if you did something like `thisQuiz: this`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with `thisQuiz: this`... `this` usually remains untouched until you use `bind`, `call` or `apply` anywhere.

Comment: @somethinghere I believe  Adjit means setting `thisQuiz: this` as a property of the `Quiz` object  and then using `thisQuiz.newQuestion()`. I tried this, but it didn't work

Comment: It won't work upon initialising, but if you do it after it _will_ work. (The reason it does not work when initialising is that your `Quiz` does not exist yet, so when it fills in that value it is still creating it and therefor is considered undefined until it is done initialising). But if you do `Quiz.thisQuiz = this`, then you can do `Quiz.thisQuiz.newQuestion()` and it will be equal to `Quiz.newQuestion()` - It's because Quiz is exactly the same as Quiz.thisQuiz - they both refer to the same location in memory, which contain the same objects.

Comment: I don't believe that this works. `var Quiz = {  score : 0, self: this...` and then use `this.newQuestion()`

Comment: It does not because of initialisation i touched on in my previous comment :)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are using `this` inside the click event and it refers to the event rather than you context. To work around you need to assign this to another variable and then use that;

```
      skipQuestion: function() {
            var self = this;
            $('#skip').click(function(){
                self.getQuestion();

            })
        },
```

`$.get` and `.click` event create their own context and thus `this` refers to their context instead of the context of quiz.

**JS**

```
(function(window){

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var Quiz = {

            score : 0,
            question: '',
            answer: '',

            init: function() {
                this.getQuestion();
                this.checkAnswer();
                this.skipQuestion();
            },

            skipQuestion: function() {
                var self = this;
                $('#skip').click(function(){
                    that.getQuestion();

                })
            },

            getQuestion: function() {
                var self = this;
                $.get('http://jservice.io/api/random', function(data){
                    $('#question').html(data[0].question);
                    self.answer = data[0].answer.toLowerCase();
                });
            },

            checkAnswer: function() {
                if($('#answer').val() === this.answer) {
                    this.score += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        Quiz.init();
    });

})(window);
```

Comment: ah ok, so that is why `this` is different here, to the `this` in the `init` function ?

Comment: So why does it not change on the `$.get()` function?